# $\mathbb{Q}$-dimension of f. g. $\mathbb{Q}[\mathbb{Z}/p^l]$-modules.

Tags: representation-theory, modules, tensor-products

My question arises from the [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220243/on-the-module-over-cyclotomic-fields)

Let $M$ be a finitely generated $\mathbb{Q}[\mathbb{Z}/p^l]$-module, where $p$ is a prime number.

Is it true that 
\begin{equation}\dim_\mathbb{Q} M\geq \frac{p}{p-1}\dim_\mathbb{Q} M
\mathbin{\mathop{\otimes}_{\mathbb{Q}[\mathbb{Z}/p^l]}}\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^l})?\end{equation}

Here, $\zeta_{p^l}$ is the $p^l$th root of the unity.

Comment: What about $M=0$.

Comment: I edited it. I also considered the case that $\mathbb{Q}[\mathbb{Z}/p^l]$-module structure on $M$ is trivial. So I modified the question into inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ring is the direct sum of fields 
$$
\frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{x^{p^{\ell}} - 1} = \bigoplus_{i=0}^{\ell} \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{\ell^i}), 
$$
and a module over your ring is just a direct sum of vector spaces over these fields; the tensor product functor you wrote just projects such a module to the $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^\ell})$-vector-space-component. The inequality is false, because you can just take $M = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^\ell})$ itself. Maybe you don't want $\mathbb{Q}$-dimension on both sides?